# How to make the following function return true or false?

Tags: javascript, function

The following function checks if some objects have the property `thumbnail`. And I want it to return `true` if the object has a thumbnail and `false` if the object doesn't:

```
function hasThumbnail (key, object) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    const value = object[key]
    if (value.constructor === Array) {
      value.forEach(obj => {
        if (obj.thumbnail) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

However, right now the function doesn't return anything. How can I make the function return `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside to get a `true` or `false` out of the iteration, if found.

```
function hasThumbnail (key, object) {
    return Object.keys(object).some(key => {
        const value = object[key]
        if (value.constructor === Array) {
            return value.some(obj => {
                return obj.thumbnail;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an `forEach`, but `return` in a loop just ends the loop so you need to do it like this:

```
function hasThumbnail (key, object)
{
    var ret = false;
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        const value = object[key]
        if (value.constructor === Array) {
            value.forEach(obj => {
                if (obj.thumbnail) {
                    ret = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    ret = false;
                    return;
                }
            })
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

This code is untested and I'm more of a jQuery guy, but the concept of return not working in a loop **should** be the same with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less verbose way:

```
function hasThumbnail(object) {
    return Object.values(object).some(prop =>
       Array.isArray(prop) && prop.some(x => x.thumbnail));
}
```

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) can be easily polyfilled.